# Loading a credit card to AndroidPay wallet programatically

Tags: android, android-pay

I want to load a credit card to Android wallet programatically. Is this possible. I see the SDK provides APIs to load loyalty cards etc... but can a VISA/MC card be loaded programatically?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add credit card to Google Pay from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app)