# How to add credit card to Google Pay from my app?

Tags: android, google-pay

I'm developing mobile banking app and obviously it manages our bank credit cards. So now I need to implement "Add this card to Google Pay" button in my app but how to do Google Pay API request for this? I am unable to find any related docs. The [only one question here on SO has answer which states that our bank should comply to PCI DSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576819/save-credit-card-to-google-pay) and its done of course. And there are a bunch of docs (including Google official) on how to add any credit card to Google Pay manually, using Google Pay app. But I need to do it automatically within my app. I realize that our bank has to has some special agreement with Google and AFAIK our bank has it. Is there any technical documentation on how to implement such feature?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This feature is currently only available to card issuers and requires additional access. Access to relevant documents on the [Android Push Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/) can be requested on the page or by following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/requesting-access?api=true

Comment: Seems like you are right and we need to request access to this doc. Like I thought it is kinda closed API/doc.

Comment: can you post the general steps which are required to implement that "add my card to my Google payment methods" button?  I need to roughly estimate the amount-of-work/effort before getting access to those closed APIs.

Comment: You'll need to sign up for the APIs to get details on how to integrate. In general terms, expect to client side integration, server side integration, encryption, and key exchange.