# Add Credit card to Google pay

Tags: android, google-pay

Want to save credit card from app to Google pay app on button click. For this checked some document and found that we need a special permission from google.

We have whitelisted our app for Google pay and for now Android push provisioning it required Google Contact. How we get that Google Contact?

This is the page asking to contact the TSP or Google Contact :

https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/requesting-access?api=true

Comment: Can you link these special documents ?

Comment: @WaLinke https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/digital_wallets/android_push_provisioning Here it is

Comment: I don't see any reference to "Google Contact" in this document.

Comment: @WaLinke https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/requesting-access?api=true here it is.

Comment: Can't you just create a Google Account ?

Comment: @WaLinke we created and fill that form but they are answering like **Can you please provide your point of contact at Google, so that we can contact them and provide you with appropriate access?**

Comment: Did you specified N/A in the contact field ? Can't you answer back ?

Comment: @WaLinke we added N/A now they reply like **Can you please contact your Network / Token Service Provider (TSP) and let them know that you are interested in Google Pay? Your TSP will be able to help with any integration, testing and launch questions you may have.**

Comment: Are you writing an app for a card issuer? Push Provisioning is intended for use by card issuers (like a bank) so that they can add their card to the Google Pay wallet. Here is a previous answer that I've provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app/57829311#57829311