# If I integrate Apple and Google pay into my app does that mean I can let my users make payments in-store?

Tags: android, ios, payment-processing, applepay, google-pay

I would like to let my app users make payments in-store using the NFC function on a payment terminal. Would integrating Apple Pay and/or Google Pay allow this to work?

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: No, payment at a payment terminal requires that they have loaded their payment card into the Apple Wallet or the Android equivalent. It is nothing to do with your app.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by integrating Apple and Google Pay into your app.

I can interpret this in one of two ways:

1. Implement the Apple and Google Pay buttons into your mobile application, or
2. Implement a button to provision your card into the Apple and Google pay wallets

If you are referring to 1, then no, it won't allow users to make payments in-store.

If you are referring to 2, then yes, it is possible, however restrictions apply. You will typically be doing this on behalf of a card issuer (like a bank), and you will have an agreement in place with Apple and/or Google. You can request access with Google by following these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/requesting-access?api=true).

Related answer for 2 can be found at: [How to add credit card to Google Pay from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app/57829311#57829311)