# I need to Add debit card from my APP to Google pay progmatically

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-pay

I am a little bit new in Google pay integration. I need to add a debit card into google pay from my android app. but I am not finding any API for that. Anyone can help me how I can add debit card programmatically from my android app to google pay directly.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't generally possible to do with Google Pay. It is up to the user to add a card directly to their Google Account.

One exception is if you happen to be the card issuer. If you are the card issuer, you can sign up for the [Android Push Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/).

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829311/12031739) for more information.