# How do I add a bank debit or credit card into Google Wallet programmatically?

Tags: android-pay, google-pay

I'm working on a project for a financial institution and they would like to **add their debit/credit card to Google Wallet automatically, from within their own app.**

I can't seem to locate the correct API for this. Any direction will be appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add credit card to Google Pay from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app)

Answer (score 2):

See my previous answer for [How to add credit card to Google Pay from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app/57829311#57829311)

The name of the feature that you are after is called [Android Push Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/). You'll need to request access via: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/requesting-access?api=true

Comment: Thank you, Soc. That's truly most helpful.

Comment: @Soc Do you know from where I can get sandbox test cards to test the push provisioning API from app(in sandbox mode)?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. You should reach out to support to see if they're able to advise.