# How to implement a link to "Add credit card to Google Wallet" in a Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-wallet

How to implement "Add credit card to Google Wallet" functionality in my xamarin app?

For example, I have Xamarin.forms app with a button "add to google wallet". When the user taps it, it should open a popup or native Google Wallet. The user can then input card number, expiry date, etc.

Comment: Specifically for bank cards, [you probably can't, unless you are a licensed bank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app).  If you just want it to open google wallet (not a specific screen, just the app itself) you can do that with an [app link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links), but I don't think they provide a specific one for "add credit card" screen.